# So, i've been trying to make a python program to take a time.sleep() input so user puts in the number then it asks which website you wanna open

Tags: python-3.x

```
import webbrowser
import time

while True:
    num = input("In How Much Time Would You Like To Open?: ")
    value = float(num)
    time.sleep(num)
    sites = input("What website would you like to open?: ")
    visit = "http://{}".format(sites)
    webbrowser.open(visit)
```

why won't this work? try it yourself and see the mistake I have really no idea please help!

Comment: Tip: the small field labelled "Title" is designed to hold just a title. The full story goes into the much larger field beneath it. (Also, do not start a question with "So" or "Hi".)

Answer (score 0):

In python3 `input()` is returning a string.  The program is converting this to a float, but then does not use it, still calling `time.sleep(num)`.  The question does not include the error message, but it probably was:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Simply using the float the code makes will fix it

```
import webbrowser
import time

while True:
    sites = input("What website would you like to open?: ")
    num   = input("In How Much Time Would You Like To Open?: ")
    value = float(num)
    time.sleep(value)   # <<-- HERE - was time.sleep(num)
    visit = "http://{}".format(sites)
    webbrowser.open(visit)
```

EDIT: Changed to ask for the website first

Comment: Okay but how would i make it so that first it would get input of which website it wants to open then the time so that after the time finishes it opens the website

Comment: Put the `sites =` line above the `num = ` line